# what is the difference between langchain and text generation web ui

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am new o this ml world, I came across two tools, one is text generation web ui like oobabooga and the other is langchain. can anyone help me understand the similarity and differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

[Text generation web UI](https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui) is just a web interface to a variety of LLM models like LLAMA 2, it lets you chat with the models that you have downloaded to ./models directory under under the source code.

[langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain) on the other hand is a framework, like flask, that you can use to create  LLM powered applications like chatPDF e.g. you can use it for moving data between python codes and an LLM API.

Answer (score 0):

langchain is a framework that automates every single step. communication with chatgpt needs alot of preparation. You have to upload a doc, read the doc, split the content into chunks, create embeddings for each chunk, stored the embeddings (vector representation of the text chunk) in a vector store, find the relavent chunk etc. with langchain, each step can be handled with one line of code.

`langchain` is for developers. On the other hand, text generation web ui, as the name says, it is a `ui`, it hides everything from the user and makes it easy for users to communicate with different AI models.